# Invoking ONC RPC from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rpc

I have a Ruby (Rails) app that needs to make some calls to a service exposed via ONC RPC.  Is there a way I can readily accomplish this in Ruby or do I need to create a proxy service using another language?

FWIW, my target platform is CentOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything for Ruby, you may want to drop into JRuby on Rails and use one of the Java libraries.

Comment: how to achieve in java the same requirement ?